# Sample Spaces, events

Tags: probability, statistics

Please note that there are matches to the following passage already on stack exchange but the question is different.

"Four universities,$1, 2, 3$, and $4$,are participating in a holiday basketball tournament. In the first round, $1$ will play $2$ and $3$ will play $4$. Then the two winners will play for the championship, and the two losers will also play. One possible outcome can be denoted by $1324$ ($1$ beats $2$ and $3$ beats $4$ in first-round games, and then $1$ beats $3$ and $2$ beats $4$).

a) List all outcomes in S.

The answer to question 'a' according to many sources is the following:

$$1324,1423,2314,2413,3124,3214,4123,42131342,1432,2341,2431,3142,3241,4132,4231$$

Now my question is how come the sample space contains $" 3214"$ because only $1$ will play $2$ and $3$ will play $4$ in the first round but here $3$ is playing $1$ and $2$ is playing $4$.

Comment: First round: $2$ beats $1$ and $3$ beats $4$. Second round: $3$ beats $2$ and $1$ beats $4$.

Comment: @barak if you can explain it a bit and post it as an answer I just might mark it as right. You  said "second round", I don't understand that

Comment: What's not to understand about "second round"?

Comment: OK now I do. Thanks